# bind_cols doesn't work with different row length

Tags: r, list

I am trying to combine 4 lists but they have different row numbers. The g1 has 4 rows and the others 5 but this may change I don't want to be restricted the number of rows

```
dataframe_list <- list(g1,g2,g3,g4)
big_data = dplyr::bind_cols(dataframe_list, )
```

and I get the following error: Error: Can't recycle `q1c` (size 5) to match `q1c_30d` (size 6).

any help?

Comment: Does `do.call(qpcR::cbind.na, dataframe_list)` work for you?

Comment: Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘knitr’ 1.31 is already loaded, but >= 1.33 is required

Comment: that is a message to update your knitr.  you may use `update.packages("knitr")` or remove the old package and install it again

Comment: after updating, I get "Error: 'cbind.na' is not an exported object from 'namespace:qpcR'"

Comment: Sorry, it would be `:::` instead of `::` as it is internal i.e. `do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, dataframe_list)`

Comment: thank you, now it works!!!

Comment: @akrun Please provide as answer!

Comment: is there any way to replace NA values with " " (empty string). Because when I use kable for all the table now I have NA values that are not correct

Answer (score 1):

We could use the `cbind.na` from `qpcR` to `cbind` `list` elements with different number of rows - `cbind.na` fills `NA` for those list elements having less number of rows

```
do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, dataframe_list)
```

Comment: Master could you please assist/help here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250774/calulate-the-mean-for-each-row-in-data-frame-by-each-group-in-r/70251279?noredirect=1#comment124185178_70251279> I already have the solution. How can I automate the names after `pmap_dfr` from a look up table. So for col S1:S2 the name should be Mean_Group A. Many thanks"

Comment: @TarJae if there are only 3 groups, your approch looks fine to me

Comment: I think there are more groups in the original dataset. And the op is asking if we can apply the new column names with the means from a lookup table called Annotation?

Comment: @TarJae sorry, I didn't see the OP's dataset.  You can do `with(Annotation, split(str_remove(Sample, "[a-z]+"),  str_c('Mean_Group_', Group))) %>% map_dfc(~ df %>% dplyr::select(all_of(.x)) %>% rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE)) %>% bind_cols(df %>% dplyr::select(Gene), .)`  The `str_remove` is becaue the OP specified it as `Sample1`, `Sample2`, etc, instead of `S1`, `S2`

Comment: @TarJae Or you may do `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Gene, names_to = 'Sample') %>% left_join(Annotation %>% mutate(Sample = str_remove(Sample, '[a-z]+'), Group = str_c('Mean_Group_', Group))) %>% dplyr::select(-Sample) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = value, values_fn = mean)`

Comment: Awwwsome! Master.