# Calulate the mean for each row in data frame by each group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I m trying to find the mean of each row in a data frame for each group in columns.
My input data is M, where the samples are grouped by annotation table:

```
M <- matrix(runif(40), nrow = 5, ncol = 8)
rownames(M) <- paste('Gene', seq(1:5), sep = "")
colnames(M) <-paste('Sample', seq(1:8), sep = "")

Annotation <- data.frame(Sample = paste('Sample', seq(1:8), sep = ""),Group = c(rep('A',2), rep('B', 2), rep('C',4)) )
```

Now I want to calculate the mean value for each rows in data frame for each group in annotation file and get another data frame/ or add to current data frame like:

[image]

The output values are random.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use `apply()`

Comment: Please share data as copy/pasteable text that we can demonstrate solutions on, not as pictures of tables.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: Thanks to akrun!** Here is a more automated version:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Gene, names_to = 'Sample') %>% 
  left_join(Annotation %>% mutate(Sample = str_remove(Sample, '[a-z]+'), Group = str_c('Mean_Group_', Group))) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Sample) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = value, values_fn = mean)
```

```
  Gene  Mean_Group_A Mean_Group_B Mean_Group_C
  <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 G1          -0.417       -0.352       0.576 
2 G2          -0.391        1.33        0.879 
3 G3          -2.23        -1.89       -0.449 
4 G4           1.71         0.912      -0.0216
5 G5           0.582        2.12        0.0838
```

**First answer:**
One way would be to use `pmap_dfr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate(pmap_dfr(across(S1:S2),
                  ~ data.frame(Mean_GroupA = mean(c(...))))) %>% 
  mutate(pmap_dfr(across(S3:S4),
                  ~ data.frame(Mean_GroupB = mean(c(...))))) %>% 
  mutate(pmap_dfr(across(S5:S8),
                  ~ data.frame(Mean_GroupC = mean(c(...)))))
```

```
 Gene         S1        S2         S3         S4        S5        S6         S7          S8 Mean_GroupA Mean_GroupB Mean_GroupC
1   G1 -2.9631013  2.128729  1.5440470 -2.2475997 -2.821792  2.789957  0.3067319  2.02967878  -0.4171862  -0.3517764  0.57614401
2   G2 -2.9881341  2.205504  0.1252083  2.5445515  2.419377  1.629860 -0.5366258  0.00373429  -0.3913150   1.3348799  0.87908623
3   G3 -2.3801595 -2.075316 -0.8376676 -2.9434839  2.162581 -1.089719 -0.5378263 -2.33118860  -2.2277379  -1.8905757 -0.44903839
4   G4  2.3143576  1.105065  1.2648060  0.5601431 -2.775243  1.145832  2.1268387 -0.58385730   1.7097114   0.9124746 -0.02160752
5   G5 -0.1625891  1.326408  1.4469643  2.8007233  2.057994 -0.041658 -2.0802055  0.39907598   0.5819093   2.1238438  0.08380163
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5"), S1 = c(-2.9631013, 
-2.9881341, -2.3801595, 2.31435765, -0.1625891), S2 = c(2.1287289, 
2.20550407, -2.0753163, 1.10506511, 1.32640774), S3 = c(1.54404698, 
0.12520826, -0.8376676, 1.26480602, 1.4469643), S4 = c(-2.2475997, 
2.54455148, -2.9434839, 0.56014312, 2.8007233), S5 = c(-2.8217917, 
2.41937685, 2.16258073, -2.7752431, 2.05799403), S6 = c(2.78995706, 
1.62985958, -1.0897194, 1.14583159, -0.041658), S7 = c(0.30673189, 
-0.5366258, -0.5378263, 2.12683874, -2.0802055), S8 = c(2.02967878, 
0.00373429, -2.3311886, -0.5838573, 0.39907598)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My data matrix is large and the number of the samples in each group is not ordered by the group. Can I add ...across(colnames(M) %in% Group1) for example?

Comment: Please see my update!

Answer (score 0):

If this is your data

```
da
              X1           X2           X3           X4           X5
id            S1           S2           S3           S4           S5
grp            A            A            B            B            C
G1     0.6899627    0.1564079    1.1781793    0.8965239    0.8775281
G2    -1.1416318    0.3727000    1.3214322   -0.5519827    0.9628846
G3    -0.7996085    2.0349177   -1.7346331    1.7266299    1.3586755
G4   -1.00741747  -0.01393747   1.10712443  -0.23152309  -0.07544300
G5  -0.009610289 -1.109753618  0.687225281  0.237404982  0.388353962
              X6           X7
id            S6           S7
grp            C            D
G1    -2.1339055   -0.8832058
G2     0.6112205    0.4707905
G3     0.6396841   -0.5601753
G4    1.24123377  -0.36939366
G5   0.420034765 -0.288319580
```

you can extract the means like this

```
d <- data.frame( t(da) )
d
  id grp         G1         G2         G3          G4           G5
1 S1   A  0.6899627 -1.1416318 -0.7996085 -1.00741747 -0.009610289
2 S2   A  0.1564079  0.3727000  2.0349177 -0.01393747 -1.109753618
3 S3   B  1.1781793  1.3214322 -1.7346331  1.10712443  0.687225281
4 S4   B  0.8965239 -0.5519827  1.7266299 -0.23152309  0.237404982
5 S5   C  0.8775281  0.9628846  1.3586755 -0.07544300  0.388353962
6 S6   C -2.1339055  0.6112205  0.6396841  1.24123377  0.420034765
7 S7   D -0.8832058  0.4707905 -0.5601753 -0.36939366 -0.288319580

data.frame( t( aggregate( cbind( G1, G2, G3, G4, G5 ) ~ grp , d, 
  function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)) ) ) )
            X1         X2         X3         X4
grp          A          B          C          D
G1   0.4231853  1.0373516 -0.6281887 -0.8832058
G2  -0.3844659  0.3847248  0.7870526  0.4707905
G3   0.6176546 -0.0040016  0.9991798 -0.5601753
G4  -0.5106775  0.4378007  0.5828954 -0.3693937
G5  -0.5596820  0.4623151  0.4041944 -0.2883196
```

##### Data

```
da <- structure(c("S1", "A", " 0.6899627", "-1.1416318", "-0.7996085", 
"-1.00741747", "-0.009610289", "S2", "A", " 0.1564079", " 0.3727000", 
" 2.0349177", "-0.01393747", "-1.109753618", "S3", "B", " 1.1781793", 
" 1.3214322", "-1.7346331", " 1.10712443", " 0.687225281", "S4", 
"B", " 0.8965239", "-0.5519827", " 1.7266299", "-0.23152309", 
" 0.237404982", "S5", "C", " 0.8775281", " 0.9628846", " 1.3586755", 
"-0.07544300", " 0.388353962", "S6", "C", "-2.1339055", " 0.6112205", 
" 0.6396841", " 1.24123377", " 0.420034765", "S7", "D", "-0.8832058", 
" 0.4707905", "-0.5601753", "-0.36939366", "-0.288319580"), .Dim = c(7L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(c("id", "grp", "G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", 
"G5"), NULL))
```